# Is there a place where I can see how all past game choices affect dragon age inquisition

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

As the title says I was wondering if there is anywhere online where I would be able to see a list of all of the choices that you make across dragon age and dragon age 2 and see how it would affect dragon age inquisition?

Answer (score -2):

[The Dragon Age Keep](https://dragonagekeep.com/) allows you tailor what choices you did in the earlier Dragon Age: Origins and Dragon Age 2. This allows you to make a save that you can use in Dragon Age: Inquisition and see how one choice affects events later on.

Furthermore, quoting their website:

> "Watch and make a few key choices in the Interactive Story Summary,
>   then use the Tapestry to further customize choices from Dragon Age:
>   Origins, Dragon Age II, and all DLCs, to create your first world
>   state."

You can read more about this [in this blog post](http://www.dragonage.com/en_US/news/introducing-the-dragon-age-keep) and check it out for yourself at https://dragonagekeep.com/

However, this service is only provided to make your own story prior to Dragon Age: Inquisition. It does not tell the tale of what happens in Dragon Age: Inquisition, I guess that's up to the player.

Gamesradar has an article about what vital decisions impact the gameplay in several major ways in later Dragon Age games, [here](http://www.gamesradar.com/dragon-ages-plot-choices-keep-tapestry/).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how the decisions affect Dragon Age: Inquisition. Also the information found in the linked Gamesradar article is wrong.